# Deleting records more than 7 days MySQLite android

Tags: android, mysql, android-sqlite

I have been trying for days to delete records older than 7 days in MySQLite android without success. I have tried:

```
database.execSQL("delete from " + MySQLite.WORKFLOW_TABLE_NAME + " where '" + MySQLite.WORKFLOW_COLUMN_DATECREATED +
    "' < 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)'");
```

and

```
database.delete(MySQLite.WORKFLOW_TABLE_NAME, "date('now') > date('" + MySQLite.WORKFLOW_COLUMN_DATECREATED + "', '+7 days')",
  null);
```

and

```
database.delete(MySQLite.WORKFLOW_TABLE_NAME, MySQLite.WORKFLOW_COLUMN_DATECREATED + " < '"
    + dateFormat.format(range.getTime()) + "'", null);
```

and non of these is working. I am saving the date into the table using:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MySQLite.WORKFLOW_COLUMN_DATECREATED, dateFormat.format(convertStringToDate(Data.State.tripdate)));
```

The date column of the Table is created as:
    WORKFLOW_COLUMN_DATECREATED + " text not null, "

and converting the String into a Date with:

```
public Date convertStringToDate(String dateString)
{
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date date = null;
try {

  date = formatter.parse(dateString);
  System.out.println(date);
  System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return date;
```

}

Somebody helppp.

Comment: please read the doc: 1. there is no datetime type in sqlite ... 2. `SELECT date('now')` returns date in format `yyyy-MM-dd`  3. in string comparsion `'-' < '/'` ...  obviously the very naive solution is to pass formated "date now - 7 days" from java code and compare it in sql as string (as datetime string in format `yyyy/MM/dd` is comparable in the same way as strings)

Answer (score 0):

Android uses SQLite, not MySQL. You may need to familiarize yourself with a different set of [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

My preference is to always store dates and times as the long value (milliseconds since epoch) as this is far more convenient for any sort of comparison, and it's easy enough to convert to and from formatted date strings using Java classes like `Calendar` and `DateFormat`.

Failing that, I suggest you store dates in the form `yyyy-MM-dd` because this is one of the *timestring* formats SQLite accepts in the various date and time functions in the link above. Then you can easily turn the date into a comparable value (in seconds since epoch) with `STRFTIME('%s')`. Essentially the statement would look like this:

`DELETE FROM table WHERE STRFTIME('%s', column) < STRFTIME('%s', 'now', '-7 days');`

Failing that, you can use some string manipulation functions to convert your current dates into something you can pass as an argument to `STRFTIME`. Assuming all your values are `yyyy/MM/dd`, you can convert them to `yyyy-MM-dd` with the [`REPLACE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace) function. Inside the above statement it looks like this:

`DELETE FROM table WHERE STRFTIME('%s', REPLACE(column, '/', '-')) < STRFTIME('%s', 'now', '-7 days');`

Here's how I would do it in Java:

```
String selection = "STRFTIME('%s', REPLACE(" + MySQLite.WORKFLOW_COLUMN_DATECREATED
        + ", '/', '-')) < STRFTIME('%s', 'now', '-7 days')";
int numDeleted = database.delete(MySQLite.WORKFLOW_TABLE_NAME, selection, null);
```